# turbo c++ GUi Base Calculator

Tags: c++, turbo-c

I wanted to create GUI base calculator in turbo C++ which have basic math function , no mouse pointer is required in this calculator, any help and workaround is appreciated i don't know where to start in this case. [image: this type of calculator is required]

thanks for helping in advance

Comment: You'd definitely be well served by trying to find a newer compiler than Turbo C++!

Comment: Is BGI graphics even possible on a modern Windows machine?  Seriously, you should concentrate on current graphical interfaces like maybe OpenGL and yes, get a modern C++ compiler.

Comment: @PaulM: There is a WinBGI port, created to prolong suffering of students around the world. Still it is awful idea to use this, deprecated 20 years ago, library.

Comment: Question is too broad, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask